# Hide label on buttonclick nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to make a simple text clicking game to gain a better understanding of Nativescript.


I first have a label with intro text and a question. Then I have 3 buttons to give an answer to the question.


Once the user clicks one of the buttons I want the first label and the 3 buttons to disappear and the next label to appear.

Here is my code:
This is my home-page.js

```
var frameModule = require("tns-core-modules/ui/frame");
var HomeViewModel = require("./home-view-model");

var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();

exports.loaded = function (args) {
 var page = args.object;
 page.actionBarHidden = true;
 page.bindingContext = homeViewModel;
};

exports.SwordButton = function () {
 Display1 = false;
 Display2 = true;
 console.log("The Sword button was pressed");
};

exports.BowButton = function () {
 Display1 = false;
 Display2 = true;
 console.log("The Bow button was pressed");
};

exports.ShieldButton = function () {
 Display1 = false;
 Display2 = true;
 console.log("The Shield button was pressed");
};
```

This is my home-page.xml:

```
<ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout class="home-panel">
    <Label textWrap="true" text="Text game" class="h2 description-label" />

    <Label id="text1" textWrap="true" visibility="{{ Display1 ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}"
        text="It's a zombie apocalypse! You are looting a store when suddenly a zombie bursts in through the door. You frantically search for a weapon. You find a box containing a sword, a bow and a shield. Which one do you choose?"
        class="h2 description-label" />

    <Label id="text2" textWrap="true" visibility="{{ Display2 ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" text="You chose poorly." />
    <Button text="Sword" tap="SwordButton" />
    <Button text="Bow" tap="BowButton" />
    <Button text="Shield" tap="ShieldButton" />
</StackLayout>
```

Here is my home-view-model.js:

```
var observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

  function HomeViewModel() {
    var weapon;
    var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
      Display1: true,
      Display2: false,

      textFieldValue: "",
  });

  return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```

I hope I have given enough information for you to help, if not please let me know.
Hope you can help.

Comment: Similar problem is solved here https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=7gxTOc&v=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Turns out I forgot to set the new value of the Display variables.


This is what my new SwordButton function looks like.

```
exports.SwordButton = function () {
  Display1 = false;
  Display2 = true;
  console.log("The Sword button was pressed");
  homeViewModel.set("Display1", Display1);
  homeViewModel.set("Display2", Display2);
};
```

I did the same thing for the BowButton and the ShieldButton functions.